# Stanford CoreNLP Sentiment Analysis example in Java?

Tags: java, sentiment-analysis

Recently I've been trying to find an example on how to make use of the Sentiment annotation from StanFord coreNLP using Java. Unfortunately the amount of examples provided is quite limited. The examples were mostly related running the sentiment analysis model from the cmd. Would someone be able to provide a simple example of using the Sentiment annonation in Java?

Comment: Please link the APIs or documentation that you are using with the question.